# Get actual time (java, c) synchronized

Tags: java, c, winapi, time, synchronization

i am working on easy game(just for fun). 
I have server in `c` and client in `java`.

I want get actual time on `server` and on `client`, but I can not come to the same results time.

On server i am using:

```
// the system time
SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
GetSystemTime(&systemTime);

// the current file time
FILETIME fileTime;
SystemTimeToFileTime(&systemTime, &fileTime);

// filetime in 100 nanosecond resolution
ULONGLONG fileTimeNano100;
fileTimeNano100 = (((ULONGLONG) fileTime.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + fileTime.dwLowDateTime;

//to milliseconds and unix windows epoche offset removed
ULONGLONG posixTime = fileTimeNano100 / 10000 - 11644473600000;
return posixTime;
```

And i am getting time in format(output): `1750721123`

On client i am using

```
long lDateTime = new Date().getTime();
System.out.println("Date() - Time in milliseconds: " + lDateTime);

Calendar lCDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Calender - Time in milliseconds :" + lCDateTime.getTimeInMillis());
```

And i am gettin format(output):

```
Calender - Time in milliseconds :1419089968022
Date() - Time in milliseconds: 1419089968022
```

Why? Where is the problem? How can i get the same TIME?

Both programs run on the same pc(win 8.1)

Comment: The Java one is right. Where did you get the magic number for the "unix windows epoch"?

Comment: @AlanStokes Stokes i found this code on internet

Comment: Is the first example really C? If yes it must be quite macro heavy... There's no `FILETIME` defined in the C standard library for instance

Comment: How are you printing the result in the first case? The calculation looks ok, but printing a ULONGLONG requires some care.

Comment: @fge this is not (strictly conforming) standard C; this is Windows API code, and the Windows API implements a type called [`FILETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Code is correct. Use `printf("%I64ul",posixTime);`

Answer (score 1):

First of all. First block of code doesn't seem to be standard C code at all or rather you use some libraries that I just simply doesn't know.

There is no simple way to get actual time with less than a second accuracy in standard C. But here is the example with Java and C that actually works, so I hope this would help.

**Java**

package stackOverflow;

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long lDateTime = new Date().getTime();
        System.out.println(lDateTime/1000);
    }

}
```

Output: `1436200408`

**C**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct timeval tv;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    printf("%ld\n", tv.tv_sec);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `1436200418`